# R RODBC package under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, rodbc

I get below error when I try my code on ubuntu/linux R

```
> library('RODBC')
> sname <- "BLAH"
> dbname <- "BB"
> dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};server=", sname, ";database=", dbname, ";trusted_connection=true", sep = ""))
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};server=", sname,  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};server=", sname,  :
  ODBC connection failed
```

But the same code runs fine on windows R. I am using RStudio on windows while using command prompt on linux/ubuntu

```
> library("RODBC", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
> 
> sname <- "BLAH"
> dbname <- "BB"
> dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};server=", sname, ";database=", dbname, ";trusted_connection=true", sep = ""))
```

Comment: Please read the package documentation. You need to define the 'DSN' appropriately.  Someone may have done that for you on the Windows machine.

Comment: So is the SQL Server on another separate machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue and solved it with the following modification between windows and linux versions:

**on windows:**

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};server=", ...
```

**on linux:**

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver=SQLServer;server=", ...
```

the difference is just in declaring the driver, with/without curly braces and a space between `SQL` and `Server`

still searching for an explanation of **why** this works though...